# How to add a subclass of UIView to a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, drawrect

I have a class that subclasses UIView called DrawView. This class contains custom drawing in the `drawRect:` method. I want to add this to a UIScrollView programmatically in a UIViewController class controlling the view which the UIScrollView has been added to. Also, I want the instance of DrawView to be a global variable.

I kind of confused and I am not really sure of anything, except that at some point I will have to call `[scroller addSubview:drawViewInstance];`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes what you have written is correct. Also your subview should be a new class overriding the methods you need. You can maintain it globally by providing a method to return the instance more like a singleton.

Put the variable into the app delegate class. Alloc and init it and you can access it using the getter. Declare the variable in your delegate.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate].globalInstance;
```

Comment: App delegate can be accessed via [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate . So you can have your instance variable in here. I will edit my post.

Comment: `+(DrawView *)sharedDrawView{ static DrawView *sharedDrawView; if(!sharedDrawView) sharedDrawView = [[SharedDrawView] alloc] init]; return sharedDrawView;}` Each ; means a line break :)

Comment: Well thats also great. Its a singleton.